# Get user and display all their listing

Tags: wordpress

I'am newbie in coding, i want to display all the listing user in their profil page
How can i get the post type of the listing and display it in user profil page

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ):

    global $current_user;
    wp_get_current_user();
    $author_query = array('posts_per_page' => '-1','author' => $current_user->ID);
    $author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
    while($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post();
    ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>       
    <?php           
    endwhile;

else :

    echo "not logged in";

endif;
```

it display only post 'postype' i want to change the post type like page or product or listing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ):
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $author_query = array('posts_per_page' => '-1','author' => $current_user->ID);
    $author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
    while($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post();
    ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>       
    <?php           
    endwhile;

else :

    echo "not logged in";

endif;
```